# What collocates with the term login account?

Tags: prepositions

I would just like to know what prepositions are used with the term *login account*.

> Do you have a login account **for** Paypal?
>
> Do you have login account **in** Paypal?
>
> Do you have a login account **on** Paypal?

Or is there a better word that collocates with the term *login account*?

Comment: What effort have you made to find an answer?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please read the "[Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4785)" and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).To improve your question: **what do you think the answer is** and what research have you done?  Keep contributing and welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The forms I generally hear (or see written, in on-line communication), in order from most-common to least-common, are

*Do you have a PayPal account?*

*Do you have an account with PayPal?*

*Do you have an account on PayPal?* (this only occurs with on-line establishments, never with ‘brick-and-mortar’ establishments)

*Do you have an account for PayPal?*

I do not ever recall encountering *...account in PayPal?*, and *...account at PayPal?* only occurs, in my experience, when PayPal is replaced with a ‘brick-and-mortar’ establishment (e.g., a retailer or bank).

Answer (score 1):

I think "login account" sounds redundant, and I agree with the other answers that suggest "PayPal" should be used as a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). Use either "login" or "account" by itself:

> Do you have a PayPal login?
>
> Do you have a PayPal account?

Answer (score 0):

A login is a name that you enter in order to be able to use a computer system.

So, when you say "a login account," I only think about an account of some name/password/code. But you are talking about a person's account, aren't you?

I guess what you are trying to say is "Do you have a PayPal account?" or, in case you need to know if someone has the password, "Do you have the password for the PayPal account?" (a particular password for a particular account).